# Rename field using Objectify and Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I am trying a case where we changed a field name in our entity. we have something like this for example

```
class Person {
   String name; //The original declaration was "String fullName"    
}
```

According to objectify you have to use annonation `@AutoLoad("")`. This is ok and it works as Google Datastore doesn't delete the data Actually but it makes a new field so this annotation is like a mapping between the old and the new field. No problem when you are reading the whole table.

The problem arises when you apply a filter on your query (Suppose you made 5 objects with old name and 5 with new name). The result of your query depends on whether you used the old variable name or the new one (returns back only 5 but never the 10). It won't fetch both of them and map them. Any Suggestions for this problem? I hope i explained it in a clear way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest straight forward solution. fetch all data with the annonation "AutoLoad()". Then store them again. In this way they will be saved as the new field. The old one doesn't exist anymore or at least it doesn't contain any data anymore. It is like migrating the data from the old name to the new name. Anyone has better suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

If you've changed the name of your field, you need to load and re-put all your data (using the mapreduce API would be one option here). There's no magic way around this - the data you've stored exists with two different names on disk.

Comment: yeah exactly i guess this is the most convenient solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use @OldName
http://www.mail-archive.com/google-appengine-java@googlegroups.com/msg05586.html

Comment: @AutoLoad is an API/Wrapper for @OldName :). They even have then same example. check [http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Renaming_A_Field]